# Accessing Object names from Array

Tags: c++, arrays, object, for-loop

Using inheritance classes, I am looking to calculate the area of 2d shapes and area and volume of 3d shapes. I am now need to access the array determine the shape and then determine whether to calculate the area or the volume of the shape. The end goal is to loop through and provide output saying the name of the shape the area and/or the volume. How do I access the object names of the array? Thanks

```
/---------------------------------------------------------
#ifndef SHAPE_H
#define SHAPE_H

const double PI = 3.14159265359;
//Base Class---------------------------------------------
Class Shape {
    protected:
        //Dimensions
        int dimensions;
        double area;
        double volume;
    public:
        //Default Constructor
        Shape();
        //Destructor
        ~Shape();
        //Get Dimension function
        double getDimensions();
        //virtual function
        virtual double getArea();
        virtual double getVolume();
};
//Shape Type-----------------------------------------------
class TwoDimensionalShape : public Shape {
    protected:
        double d1, d2;
    public:
        double get_d1() { return d1; }
        double get_d2() { return d2; }
        double set_d1(double x) { d1 = x; }
        double set_d2(double x) { d2 = x; }
};
class ThreeDimensionalshape : public Shape {
    protected:
        double d1, d2, d3;
    public:
        double get_d1() { return d1; }
        double get_d2() { return d2; }
        double get_d3() { return d3; }
        double set_d1(double x) { d1 = x; }
        double set_d2(double x) { d2 = x; } 
        double set_d3(double x) { d3 = x; } 
};
//two dimensionals Shape classes-------------------------
class Circle : public TwoDimensionalShape {
    public:
        Circle(); //default constructor
        Circle( double r); //regular constructor
        double getArea(); //get area function
};
class Square : public TwoDimensionalShape {
    public:
        Square();
        Square(double dim);
        double getArea(); 
};
class Triangle : public TwoDimensionalShape {
    public:
        Triangle();
        Triangle(double dim, double dim2); 
        double getArea(); 
};
//three dimensional shape classes-------------------------
class Sphere : public ThreeDimensionalshape {
    public:
        Sphere();
        Sphere(double dim);
        double getArea();
        double getVolume();
};
class Cube : public ThreeDimensionalshape{
    public:
        Cube();
        Cube(double dim);
        double getArea();
        double getVolume(); 
};
class Tetrahedron : public ThreeDimensionalshape{
    public:
        Tetrahedron();
        Tetrahedron(double dim);
        double getArea();
        double getVolume();
};
```

--

```
//---------------------------------------------------------
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cmath.h>

#include "shape.h" //header file

using namespace std;
//----------------------------------------------
//Default constructor
Shape::Shape() : dimensions(0), area(0), volume(0) { }
//Regular constructor
Shape::Shape(int d) : {
    dimensions = d;
}
//Function getDimensions
double Shape::getDimensions() {
    return dimensions;
}

//Two dimensional shapes-----------------------------------
//Default constructor--------------------
Circle::Circle() { 
    d1 = 1 ;
}
//Regular constructor--------------------
Circle::Circle( double r ) {
    d1 = r;
}
//Circle area
double Circle::getArea() {
    area = PI * pow( d1, 2 );
    return area;
}
//Default constructor--------------------
Square::Square() {
    d1 = 1 ;
    d2 = 1;
}
//Regular constructor--------------------
Square::Square( double dim ){
    d1 = dim;
    d2 = dim;
}
//Square area
double Square::getArea(){
    area = pow( d1, 2 );
    return area;
}
//Default constructor--------------------
Triangle::Triangle(){
    d1 = 1;
    d2 = 1;
}
//Regular constructor--------------------
Triangle::Triangle(double dim, double dim2){
    d1 = dim;
    d2 = dim2;
}
//Triangle area
double Triangle::getArea(){
    area = (d1 * d2) / 2;
}
//Three dimensional shapes-----------------------------------
//Default constructor---------------------
Sphere::Sphere(){
    d1 = 1;
    d2 = 1;
    d3 = 1;
}
//Regular constructor---------------------
Sphere::Sphere(double dim) : {
    d1 = dim;
    d2 = dim;
    d3 = dim;
}
//Sphere area
double Sphere::getArea(){
    area = 4 * PI * pow( d1, 2 );
    return area;
}
//Sphere volume
double Sphere::getVolume(){
    volume = (4/3) * PI * pow( d1, 3 );
    return volume;
}
//Default constructor---------------------
Cube::Cube(){
    d1 = 1;
    d2 = 1;
    d3 = 1;
}
//Regular constructor---------------------
Cube::Cube(double dim){
    d1 = dim;
    d2 = dim;
    d3 = dim;
}
//Cube area
double Cube::getArea(){
    area = pow( d1, 2 );
    return area;
}
//Cube Volume
double Cube::getVolume(){
    volume = pow( d1, 3 );
    return volume;
}
//Default constructor---------------------
Tetrahedron::Tetrahedron(){
    d1 = 1;
    d2 = 1;
    d3 = 1;
}
//Regular constructor---------------------
Tetrahedron::Tetrahedron(double dim){
    d1 = dim;
    d2 = dim;
    d3 = dim;
}
//tetrahedron area
double Tetrahedron::getArea(){
    area = sqrt(3) * pow( d1, 2);
    return area;
}
//tetrahedron volume
double Tetrahedron::getVolume(){
    volume = pow(d1, 3) / (6 * sqrt(2));
    return volume;
}
```

--

```
/---------------------------------------------------------
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cmath.h>

#include "shape.h" //header file

using namespace std;

int main() {
//Pointer Array--------------------------------------------
    Shape* arr[6];
//Assign Shape Dimensions and to Array
    Circle cir(2);  //declares value for circle ~ cir is var name
        arr[0] = &cir; //assigns cir var to array position 0
    Square sqr(3);
        arr[1] = &sqr;
    Triangle tri(4, 2);
        arr[2] = &tri;  
    Sphere sph(5);
        arr[3] = &sph;
    Cube cb(6);
        arr[4] = &cb;
    Tetrahedron trhd(7);
        arr[5] = &trhd;
//Loop each index of array and perform calculation
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; ++i)
    {
        cout << ""
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't compile, it has many errors.

Comment: You could add a `isThreeDimensional` member function. Or `getDimensions` if you expect to have 1D or 4D shapes as well.

Comment: Why do you need to keep 2D and 3D shapes in the same array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to add something like `toString` method to your Shape class and try to override it in your inherited classes like :

```
Class Shape{
...
public:
std::string toString();
...
}
```

Implement and override it in the subclasses:

```
std::string Shape::toString()
{
   return "This is a simple shape";
}

std::string Cube::toString()
{
   return "Cube";
}

...
```

through the power of polymorphism, you will get the object name in your for loop just by calling:

```
cout << arr[i].toString() << ...
```

Comment: Should I put the name of the object in the constructor along with the parameters or keep it separate and use something tostring() or name it getName() for a method? @Pooya

Comment: @Bigboy6 what ever mechanism you want to use, you need to declare a function (either toString or getName) to the Shape class and override it in lower classes so you can use polymorphism